# What is the type of/how do I initialize 'currentDevice' in this code?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, autofocus

I'm trying to tell the camera in my app (which is build around OpenFrameworks) to auto focus. After reading [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095007/ios-avfoundation-tap-to-focus) I read through the [AV Foundation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html) on how to set the focus mode. The code they give as an example is:

```
if ([currentDevice isExposureModeSupported:AVCaptureExposureModeContinuousAutoExposure]) {
    CGPoint exposurePoint = CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f);
    [currentDevice setExposurePointOfInterest:exposurePoint];
    [currentDevice setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeContinuousAutoExposure];
}
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to initialize currentDevice outside the if statement, and it's not in the documentation. How should it be initialized/what type is it? Thanks.

Comment: AVCaptureDevice? Your question is not clear.

Comment: @Desdenova I don't know what currentDevice is. To use it I of course need to initialize it outside the if statement. I don't now how to make that initialization.

Comment: I guess reading this would be sufficient. http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1554

Comment: @Desdenova Xcode isn't recognizing AVCaptureDevice as a type in my code for some reason

Comment: Ah. Was missing an import for some reason. #import <AVFoundation/AVCaptureDevice.h>

Comment: You need to link your binary with `AVFoundation.framework` and import it on your header file.

Comment: Try using [UIDevice currentDevice] instead of just currentDevice

Comment: @Desdenova works perfectly. Write an answer so I can give you credit - appreciate the help!

Comment: @akashg That seems to work in terms of not throwing an error but the compiler did put out a warning saying: "'UIDevice' may not respond to 'isInFocusModeSupported:' I appreciate the help though, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read more about the [AVCaptureDevice Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

It refers to front or the back side camera. And don't forget to import the `AVFoundation.framework`

Comment: #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>