# Captured image flipped horizontally

Tags: ios, xcode, camera, uiimageview, avcapturesession

Hello I am using an avcapturesession in xcode to make a live camera screen so I can take photos (similar to the snapchat setup). The camera is fully functional and I have set it up so I can use the front or back camera. The back camera works fine and I can capture an image and it previews how I need it, however the front camera previews ok but when the image is captured, in the preview it is flipped and I can't see where this is occurring.

Heres my code of for the session:

```
- (void) initializeCamera {
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;

AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
[captureVideoPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.imagePreview.bounds;
[self.imagePreview.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];

UIView *view = [self imagePreview];
CALayer *viewLayer = [view layer];
[viewLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

CGRect bounds = [view bounds];
[captureVideoPreviewLayer setFrame:bounds];

NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devices];
AVCaptureDevice *frontCamera = nil;
AVCaptureDevice *backCamera = nil;

for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {

    NSLog(@"Device name: %@", [device localizedName]);

    if ([device hasMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {

        if ([device position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack) {
            NSLog(@"Device position : back");
            backCamera = device;
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Device position : front");
            frontCamera = device;
        }
    }
}

if (!FrontCamera) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:backCamera error:&error];
    if (!input) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: trying to open camera: %@", error);
    }
    [session addInput:input];
}

if (FrontCamera) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:frontCamera error:&error];
    if (!input) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: trying to open camera: %@", error);
    }
    [session addInput:input];

}

stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
[stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

[session addOutput:stillImageOutput];

[session startRunning];
}
- (void) capImage {
AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in stillImageOutput.connections) {

    for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]) {

        if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] ) {
            videoConnection = connection;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (videoConnection) {
        break;
    }
}

NSLog(@"about to request a capture from: %@", stillImageOutput);
[stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

    if (imageSampleBuffer != NULL) {
        NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
        [self processImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
    }
}];
}

- (void) processImage:(UIImage *)image {
haveImage = YES;

if([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) { //Device is ipad
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(3072, 4088));
    [image drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 3072, 4088)];
    UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 3072, 4088);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([smallImage CGImage], cropRect);

    [captureImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]];

    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

}else{ //Device is iphone
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1280, 2272));
    [image drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 1280, 2272)];
    UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIImage * flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:smallImage.CGImage scale:smallImage.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored];

    smallImage = flippedImage;

    CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1280, 2272);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([smallImage CGImage], cropRect);


    [captureImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]];

    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
}
}
```

I also want to add touch to focus and flash but I don't know where I have to implement the code here is what I have found:

flash-

for the flash all I can find regarding the torch is a toggle. I can't find a way to make it only come on and work like apples camera apps flash.

tap to focus -

[ios AVFoundation tap to focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095007/ios-avfoundation-tap-to-focus)

Comment: Truth is, that is the default behavior for front-facing cameras. Take a picture with your front camera and observe how your phone displays it. Happens on android phones too. The front camera mimics a mirror so that you can use it naturally, hence, the output image is flipped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that is the default behavior for the front-facing camera. Try flipping the output image manually right before it is displayed.

Comment: Ok but when i change the flipped thing in Process image:       UIImage * flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:smallImage.CGImage scale:smallImage.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored];                                                    The UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored doesn't do anything to the results and i only want it to flip the front facing camera.

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot help you from here. You could try looking up one of the many camera repositories on github and diving into their code to see how they do it, however. There are several that have solved this exact problem.

Comment: well i cant find one maybe you could provide a link

Comment: Compiled, confirmed the front facing mode doesn't flip the image.